# Controller's method doesn't getting two parametrs

Tags: java, jsp

I have simple Controller which must do something task.
The task is change status of object in DB.
From jsp I send two parameters bur when I click on button which send paraments I have "404 not found"

My controller's method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/tests")
public class TestController {

private TestInterfaceService testService;

@Autowired(required = true)
@Qualifier(value = "testService")
public void setTestService(TestInterfaceService testService) {
    this.testService = testService;
}

@RequestMapping("/review/{id}")
public String editTest(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("test", this.testService.getTestById(id));
    model.addAttribute("questions",  this.testService.getListQuestionsById(id));
    return "review";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/choise/{id}/{status}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String changeStatus(@PathVariable("id") int id, @PathVariable("status") String status, Model model) {
    this.testService.getTestById(id).setStatus(status);
    this.testService.updateTest(this.testService.getTestById(id));
    model.addAttribute("test", this.testService.getTestById(id));
    model.addAttribute("questions", this.testService.getListQuestionsById(id));
    return "review";
    }
}
```

My jsp page button:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Choise</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a
                    href="<c:url value='/tests/choise/${test.id}/${"Approve"}' />">Approve</a></li>
                <li><a
                    href="<c:url value='/tests/choise/${test.id}/${"Return"}' />">Return
                        author</a></li>
                <li><a
                    href="<c:url value='/tests/choise/${test.id}/${"Refuse"}' />">Refuse</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Remove the last slash(/) in request Mapping and try and let us know, it is working or not.

Comment: What if you add contextPath? E.g. `<c:url value='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/tests/choise/${test.id}/${"Approve"}' />` ?